# How can I prevent Skyrim from freezing at the load screen?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I recently got *Skyrim Legendary Edition* for the 360. I started up a new character and everything was going smoothly and I was having a grand old time for a week or so.

Now the game keeps freezing on the loading screen very frequently. I've experienced 4-5 freezes already. There was one time where it froze while I was walking around. The majority of the time, however, it freezes when it is on the loading screen with the tips. The sound will cut out, nothing moves, and the tips don't fade in or out anymore. I can't access the guide either. I have to manually shut down the Xbox in order to get it anything back.

I've looked on forums and tried a bunch of things but none have really helped. I've tried disabling auto-saves as well as clearing the game cache (`LB` + `RB` + `X`).

I don't know if this matters, but I installed the DLC off the second disc first. Then, I installed the main game. When I ran the game for the first time, the patch downloaded and applied. The disk is new too.

Any tips on what I can do? Is my game save corrupted or something? I really want to enjoy this game but the freezing is really making this a less than stellar experience. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try deleting the updates(not your saves) in the system dash storage. Also the DLC, then reinstall before loading any saves(back them up to a USB to be sure). Let me know how much space is left on your HDD. Then go to the HDD and press "x" to show deletion suggestions(don't delete, just look), then look for any "!" next to any  files (this shows if they are corrupted or not downloaded fully) and get rid of them.

Answer (score 2):

Delete your unused saved games. Worked on my Xbox

Answer (score 0):

Go to the settings menu, and turn off all saves (loading screen saves, saves on wait, and saves on menu)